# Show/Hide table elements that were randomly generated using click event

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple tables that are randomly generated. I only want the first row of each table displayed with the rest of the rows hidden. When I click on the visible row for a table I want the rest of its rows/contents to show/hide. How would I accomplish this using Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide all the rows but the first:

```
$("table tbody tr:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

To make them visible when you click on the first row:

```
$("table tbody tr:first-child").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().show();
});
```

Alternatively you may want to organise your tables slightly differently (if possible):

```
<style type="text/css">
table tbody tr { display: none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("table thead tr").click(function() {
    $("tbody tr", $(this).parents("table")[0]).show();
  });
});
</script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr> ... first row is in thead not tbody ... </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr> ... row1 .. </tr>
  <tr> ... row2 .. </tr>
  <tr> ... row3 .. </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There are lots of ways to skin this particular cat.

Answer (score 1):

You should write some functions like this:

```
function AttachEvent(tableId)
{
    $("#" + tableId + " tbody tr:first-child").click(ToggleRows);
}

function ToggleRows(e)
{
    // get src table of e
    // you can find code for this on SO or quirksmode.org (or basically anywhere)

    $(src).find("tr").hide();
    $(src).find("tr:first-child").show();
}
```

If you call AttachEvent with the id of the table when it is generated, it will bind the event to the first row.

These functions assume that the table is generated with all the rows except row[0] set to display:none.

I haven't tested this, but the theory should work. You may need to change some things like which event to bind, and whether to use the tr or the tds for showing/hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar need, but show/hide tbody (jQuery seemed to crash when trying to toggle lots of rows). My tables are identified by class 'datatable' and I use .toggle() (available since jQuery version 1.0) based on Cletus' solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //SK toggles datatables (show/hide tbody when clicking thead)
       $('table.datatable thead tr').on('click', function( event ) { 
           $('tbody', $(this).parents('table')[0]).toggle(); });

})
```

this assumes you have your tables organised according to html5 spec with thead and tbody.
see also http://api.jquery.com/toggle/